# Jenkins Slave Swap Space

Tags: jenkins, repo

In my Jenkins setup there is a single upstream build that triggers several downstream projects that run on slave nodes. I recently added an additional slave node with the same settings (except IP and labels) as currently working slaves. When the new slave tries to run a job, however, none of the files pulled by the upstream SCM are there to run. Therefore, I receive a file not found error. I've spent the morning trying to figure out why to no avail. The console output, the Jenkins log, and the gerrit repo log don't have any other relevant information.

The main difference is that the new computer is a small ARM board (others are x86). In the new slave's attributes, it shows 3GB of free disk space but 0 byes of swap space. Does anyone know if a swap space > 0 is a requirement? I figured it would copy to disk. I've been searching the documentation and configuration settings but can't seem to find any other leads.

Comment: It sounds like there is some other configuration problem to me

Comment: jGritty, I think you're right. After looking through Jenkins configuration setttings for the entire day yesterday I thought I'd ask here in case someone knew of a Jenkins settings that I didn't. I currently think it's a permission or network file share problem which isn't turning up in any of the logs that I'm looking at. As I'm not sure at the moment, it still could be a Jenkins problem, but I'm learning towards that being a no.